# how to stop multiframe

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

i am doing my Final Year Project. It regarding Kinect. I want to print a flytext when a gesture is met. but i came about multiframe. Below list is my code.

```
public void checkHand(Joint head, Joint rightHand, Joint leftHand)
{
    bool action;
    int i;

    action = (rightHand.Position.Y > head.Position.Y);

    if (action == true)
    {
        for(i=0;i<1;i++)
        {
        FlyingText.NewFlyingText(this.screenRect.Width / 30, new Point(this.screenRect.Width / 2, this.screenRect.Height / 2), "right Hand!");
        }
        action = false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain more.  What do you mean by "but I came about multiframe"?

Comment: Hi, the following question is solve. Basically is just to declare global variable to solve this error.